# Creating a google adwords API application using OAuth

Tags: ruby, oauth-2.0, google-ads-api

I am trying to create a ruby script that will use contents from google AdWords API.
However, I am having trouble setting up the OAuth methods. The [api docs](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/authentication) mention that we need to set up the adwords service in the [api console](https://code.google.com/apis/console) but the AdWords is not mentioned there. What api should I be using for this?

In the adwords_api.yml, following are some of the values that I am using:

```
:oauth_consumer_key: 123456789046-abcd5ef2ghijkl1mno1p2qrstuvwx1y713.apps.googleusercontent.com
:oauth_consumer_secret: AbcDeF1G_HIJK1a13UKz-PAO
# If you manage or store access token manually, you can specify it here.
#:oauth_token: INSERT_OAUTH_TOKEN_HERE
# If you need to change signature method, specify it here.
#:oauth_signature_method: HMAC-SHA1
# Token secret for HMAC-SHA1 method.
#:oauth_token_secret: INSERT_OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET_HERE
```

As I am new to OAuth, are the steps I am following correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the easiest ways to use OAuth in ruby is with [OmniAuth](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth). They have a great community maintained list of RubyGems on their wiki. You should try the omniauth-google-oauth2 gem.

First set up a client id on google. [Here's a how to](https://developers.google.com/console/help/#generatingoauth2).

Using that gem, I think you can just pass in the adwords api url in the scope. So your config/initializers/omniauth.rb should look something like this.

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google_oauth2, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET,
    {
        name: "adwords",
        approval_prompt: "",
        scope: "https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/"
    }
end
```

Then you can link to "/auth/adwords" and that will take the user to the google login.